# Chi-square test restriction for contingency tables with observed counts

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have the following 2X2 contingency table with **observed** counts to perform `Chi-square` test. But i've read about `Chi-square` test restriction:

"**If any expected counts are less than 5, then some other test should be used (e.g., Fisher exact test for 2x2 contingency tables)**"

I'm confused, since in my case the contingency table contains **observed** count not the **expected** ones. Is that restriction related to **observed** counts as well?
[image: Contigency table]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see your table, there is seemingly some problem with your image. Even though the table shows the observed number of cases, nothing prevents you from computing the expected number under the null distribution (likely, independence or homogeneity). Then you can check if the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The table has attached now.

Comment: I'm wondering, if there is any straightforward way (may be a special function in `R`) to count expected counts?

Comment: I thought, the common approach is just applying the same restriction to the observed frequencies. Am i right?

Comment: You can use for instance  result <- loglin(table, margin=c(1,2), fit=TRUE). In the component  result$fit you will find the expected counts.